# HTML5 Canvas created JPEG is "corrupt" or "damaged"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a simple HTML5 Canvas object that, once saved to a file, opens perfeclty in Photoshop and looks correct, but according to Windows and OSX is "corrupted" or "damaged".

The code I'm using is very simple:

JavaScript:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
    format: 'jpeg',
    quality: 0.8
});
```

And then sending `dataURL` via AJAX:

```
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "scripts/saveImage.php",
         data: {
            imgBase64: dataURL
         }
      })
```

To a simple PHP script:

```
$imageBase64 = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$imageData = base64_decode($imageBase64);
file_put_contents($fileName,$imageData);
```

The file is created file. I *can* open it in Photoshop and it looks exactly as expected. A HEX editor shows that has `JFIF` in its headers, which is as you'd expect for JPEG, too:

[image]

But you can't open the file in Windows or OSX preview:

[image]

Have I done something wrong? Is there something in the file header that's throwing off Windows/OSX? Or this expected behavior for a JPEG created in this way?

Comment: This is `toDataURL({
    format: 'jpeg',
    quality: 0.8
})` the browser API? Or you are using some additional library? Additional plugin? Far as I know the use correct is: `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.8);`

Comment: Could you attach a broken JPEG file?

Comment: I'm using FabricJS, perhaps that's the reason? I'll see if I can attach an image.

Comment: I had the same problem, it turned out the "dataURL" started with `data/base64encoded` or something of the same nature, and then followed the image. I had to remove the beginning and then it worked. EDIT: Here's the exact code `base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', \Input::data('base64image'))));`

Comment: @php_nub_qq Thank you so much!!! Put it in an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, it turned out the "dataURL" started with `data:image/png;base64,` which is confusing the reader programs such as windows media viewer etc.

To solve the problem I used this code

```
$file = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', \Input::data('base64image'))));
```

I guess you would have to change that to

```
$file = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $_POST['imgBase64'])));
```

Honestly, I don't remember what the purpose of the first `str_replace` is and that is the reason I've included it in the answer, because it may break something if I removed it.

Comment: It's possibly because you were sending the image via the URL? I kept it in, even though I'm POSTing the data, and it still worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chuck I just had another idea for performance improvement - instead of using str_replace you can use substr and remove the first x characters, since this is always going to be in the beginning and is of constant length. Additionally, no it isn't sent through the url, that's a pretty bad idea :D